# Want to run my website in IE11, but in edge document mode

Tags: internet-explorer-11, x-ua-compatible, ie11-developer-tools

We have created an application that works well in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Edge. Now one of user tried to use Internet Explorer and there were a lot of UI issues.

We have tried setting meta tags, to set document mode to edge in IE11, but it's not working.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">`

We don't want to fix UI issues as it is working fine in edge, so just want to use edge document mode in IE11.

Comment: Can you explain the detailed error message about the UI issues, try to use [F12 developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255006(v=vs.85)) to check which part of code will display this error? Besides, please check your code, whether you are using some plugin, whether they are compliant with IE browser?

Comment: Edge document mode (which is the default document mode for IE11 unless your website changes that) has nothing to do with Microsoft Edge. If IE11 doesn't show the website correctly in that mode, then you either need to add some kind of fallback code for IE or inform the user that IE is not supported (which is the preferred outcome anyway--IE only receives emergency security updates now).

Comment: so my assumption was if it's working in edge, it should also working in ie also as both of them use the same edge render engine. However, I have to fix some of my broken HTML to make it work. Looks like meta tag is irrelevant. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from [What does <meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=edge”> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do)
that IE11 edge mode will use the highest modes of IE11, but it doesn't know about the Edge-browser itself.